# Javascript pop up window with inner html does not open

Tags: javascript, html, css

My pop up window in javascript does not show any content. It does not even open. I've written innerHTML in the javascript pop up window by creating a div id(mainBody) for my tictactoe.html page.

HTML code for button that open popup window:

```
<input type="image" id="buttonimage2" alt="game2"
    src="canon.png" onclick="newWindow();">
```

Javascript:

```
{
     var newWindow = window.open("tictactoe.html", "myWindow", "width=500,height=700,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
     newWindow.focus();
     newWindow.onload = function(){
      let content = "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='window.print();'>Confirm</button>";
      newWindow.document.getElementById('mainBody').innerHTML = content;
     } 
     newWindow.window.close();
  }
```

HTML code for tictactoe page that should be displayed in pop up window:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="mainBody" >
```

It should be mentioned that my background for the main html page is a video, and I've made the position of all the elements on it absolute.

Comment: Did you enable popups for your page? There's usually an icon at the right of the omnibar.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yeah, I did